# How can I get a list of programs in my path from Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, path

How can I list all available UNIX commands from Perl?

Comment: Have you tried looking for executable files in $ENV{PATH}? What have you tried? Is this homework?

Comment: First you have to define "UNIX command".

Comment: I got the answer... I didn't thought about $ENV{path}

Comment: One thing you might consider is actually learning Perl. Your questions show that you don't even try to figure things out on your own. That's okay once or twice, but that's almost all of your SO history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
perl -MFile::Find -le 'find sub {print if -f and -x _}, split ":", $ENV{PATH}'
```

This code looks in each directory in your path (`split ":", $ENV{PATH}`) for files (`-f`) that are executable (`-x`), and prints the ones it finds.  You may want to read about

- [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html)
- [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)
- [%ENV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%ENV)
- [filetest operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

An alternative that does not search subdirectories of the directories in the `PATH` is

```
perl -le '-f and -x _ and print for map { glob "$_/*" } split ":", $ENV{PATH}'
```

Comment: @ephemient Good point, I don't normally see subdirectories in bin directories though.

Comment: My ~/bin is a git repository, there's a way to get subdirs in your bin directory.